# Can I use regexp captured string into rsyslog paths?

Tags: regular-expression, rsyslog

Say I want to filter logs to use different files per user ID, I can write one rule per uid as here :

```
if $msg contains 'uid=500' then /var/log/uid/500
if $msg contains 'uid=501' then /var/log/uid/501
if $msg contains 'uid=502' then /var/log/uid/502
```

I would like to write one single line by using a regexp capture like this:

```
if $msg contains 'uid=\([0-9]+\)' then /var/log/uid/\1
```

Is it possible and how please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using a [property replacer](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/property_replacer.html). 
Put in your `rsyslog.conf` or similar a line defining a template that is the desired format of the filename, and use it in the action when you match the input line. For example,

```
$template myfile,"/var/log/uid/%msg:R,ERE,1,FIELD:.*?uid=([0-9]+).*--end%"
if (re_match($msg, "uid=[0-9]+")) then {
 action(type="omfile" dynaFile="myfile")
 stop
}
```

The template says the template variable `myfile` is the string including the `msg` property replaced by a regex (R) match, extended (ERE), group capture 1 (1), (and if no match, keep the original FIELD). The actual regex is the `.*?uid=([0-9]+).*` part. The `--end` is an obligatory part of the `%...:R,...--end%` sequence.

The lines following are the usual Rainer Script test for the lines you want to match, and where to place the result.