# rsyslog: send logs to different file by filtering syslogs

Tags: logs, rsyslog, syslog

I have a CentOS based rsyslog server which have the below settings, where it's getting all the remote NATing events from multiple hosts.

```
$template TmplcpFW, "/var/log/%HOSTNAME%.log"
if ($hostname == ["CP1CGNAT","CP2CGNAT"]) then ?TmplcpFW
& ~
```

Sample log output in /var/log/CP1CGNAT

```
<150>1 2018-12-20T16:07:00.482369+01:00 2018-12-20 15 - - - 06:59: CP1CGNAT_O_Poland{OR_NAT}[jservices-nat]: JSERVICES_NAT_RULE_MATCH: proto 6 (TCP) application: any, xe-1/0/1.1718:100.70.0.2:59794 -> 109.32.8.15:80, Match NAT rule-set: (null), rule: OR_NAT_Poland, term: t1
<150>1 2018-12-20T16:07:00.482369+01:00 2018-12-20 15 - - - 06:59: CP1CGNAT_O_France{OR_NAT}JSERVICES_SESSION_OPEN: application:none, xe-1/0/1.1718 100.70.0.2:59794 [55.93.69.53:26620] ->  109.32.8.15:80 (TCP) 
<150>1 2018-12-20T16:07:11.091313+01:00 2018-12-20 15 - - - 07:10: CP1CGNAT_O_UK{OR_NAT}JSERVICES_SESSION_CLOSE: application:none, xe-1/0/1.1718 100.70.0.2:59778 [55.93.69.60:40136] ->  109.32.8.15:80 (TCP)
```

I have configured NAT device service with prefix as 'syslog host 10.10.10.10 log-prefix CP1CGNAT_O_Poland'

Now I would like to separate above logs into different directories/files based on prefix values with timestamps like -

```
/Poland/Logs_Poland_2018-12-20, /France/Logs_France_2018-12-20, /UK/Logs_UK_2018-12-20
```

Can you suggest how to achieve this in rsyslog ?

---

Update taken from comments:

I have used the different log-prefixs (configured in NAT device) as filter conditions and used in templates as (total 10 similar templates):

```
$template TmplcpFW_P, "/var/log/NIPFW/Poland/Poland_%HOSTNAME%_%$year%.%$month%.%$day%.log" 
if ($hostname == ["CP1CGNAT","CP2CGNAT"]) and $msg contains 'CP1CGNAT_O_Poland' then ?TmplcpFW_P 
$template TmplcpFW_F, "/var/log/NIPFW/France/France_%HOSTNAME%_%$year%.%$month%.%$day%.log" 
if ($hostname == ["CP1CGNAT","CP2CGNAT"]) and $msg contains 'CP1CGNAT_O_France' then ?TmplcpFW_F
```

Now I want all the matching logs from above conditions to go into corresponding directories/files and remaining logs in /var/log/messages.

Comment: You can extract any part of a message if you can write a regex pattern for it. see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471648/119298)

Comment: I have copied your comments into your question, so they are easier to read (you can edit your question at any time, and just refer to the change in a short comment). If I understand you, you now have 10 templates and 10 `if ...` statements that do exactly what you want. The only thing I see missing is the line `& ~` after each `if ...` statement. That would stop the matched message from any further handling. Did you want something more than that?